# Create php code from UPDATE SQL statement (codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this query statement in SQL. I am using CodeIgniter and I would like to create these statements inline in PHP code.

```
UPDATE `dbhpl`.`pelayanan` 
    SET `pelayanan`.`ID_STATUS` = CASE 
    WHEN `pelayanan`.`LAMA` > `pelayanan`.`ESTIMASI` THEN '1' 
    WHEN `pelayanan`.`LAMA` <= `pelayanan`.`ESTIMASI` THEN '2' 
END
```

How is the code for controller.php and model.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Model Function :

```
public function update_special() {
        $str = "UPDATE dbhpl.pelayanan SET "
                . "pelayanan.ID_STATUS = "
                . "CASE WHEN pelayanan.LAMA > pelayanan.ESTIMASI THEN '1'"
                . " WHEN pelayanan.LAMA <= pelayanan.ESTIMASI "
                . "THEN '2' END";
        $this->db->query($str);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

> Controller Function

```
 function controller_function(){
        return $this->model->update_special();
    }
```